# why does b'(and sometimes b' ') show up when I split some HTML source[Python]

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x

I'm fairly new to Python and programming in general. I have done a few tutorials and am about 2/3 through a pretty good book. That being said I've been trying to get more comfortable with Python and proggramming by just trying things in the std lib out.

that being said I have recently run into a wierd quirk that I'm sure is the result of my own incorrect or un-"pythonic" use of the urllib module(with Python 3.2.2)

```
import urllib.request

HTML_source = urllib.request.urlopen(www.somelink.com).read()

print(HTML_source)
```

when this bit is run through the active interpreter it returns the HTML source of somelink, however it prefixes it with b'
for example

```
b'<HTML>\r\n<HEAD> (etc). . . .
```

if I split the string into a list by whitespace it prefixes every item with the b'

I'm not really trying to accomplish something specific just trying to familiarize myself with the std lib. I would like to know why this b' is getting prefixed

also bonus -- Is there a better way to get HTML source WITHOUT using a third party module. I know all that jazz about not reinventing the wheel and what not but I'm trying to learn by "building my own tools"

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "b" prefix means that the type is *bytes* not *str*.  To convert the bytes into text, use the *decode* method and name the appropriate encoding.  The encoding is often found in the "Content-Type" header:

```
>>> u = urllib.request.urlopen('http://cnn.com')
>>> u.getheader('Content-Type')
'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
>>> html = u.read().decode('utf-8')
>>> type(html)
<class 'str'>
```

If you don't find the encoding in the headers, try *utf-8* as a default.

Answer (score 2):

`b''` is a literal bytes object. There is no `b''` objects in memory, only `bytes`. It is just a notation for bytes objects in your source code. Plain quotes `''` in the source code create 'str' objects (Unicode strings).

If `bytes` object represents a text (not a binary data such as an image) then in general you should decode it to Unicode string as soon as possible. [You should know the character encoding of the text](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

HTML parsers such as `lxml.html`, `BeautifulSoup` may convert bytes to Unicode without your intervention.

If you don't know encoding then it might be none-trivial to detect it e.g., read [how feedparser detects character encoding [2006]](http://web.archive.org/web/20110625112646/http://feedparser.org/docs/character-encoding.html).